# IcCube - Embedded Dashboard using relative report path

Tags: embedding, subreport, iccube-reporting

In IcCube V7 reporting, I could use either absolute or relative path for referencing sub reports to be opened in an "embedded dashboard" widget.

I did not success to do the same in V8.2.2. (only absolute path seems to work)

Isn't it still an available functionality (relative path)? tried on the IcCube Live Demo with no luck :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is not (yet) added to the reporting. We'll add it to the next V8.3 release. Then, for example, you can use the relative path `Repetition Widget` instead of the absolute path `shared:/Live Demo/Miscellaneous/Repetition Widget`.